# ¿Cómo se declara un diccionario vacío en Python?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Para crear un diccionario vacío en Python se puede usar una de estas dos formas:

```
mi_dicc = dict()

mi_dicc = {}
```

Ambas son válidas, funcionan y son equivalentes. Sin embargo, leo [un comentario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424942/creating-a-new-dict-in-python#comment21477676_8424955) que dice:

> Aparentemente `dict()` en CPython 2.7 es más lento (¿6 veces más?), mira [The Performance Impact of Using dict() Instead of {} in CPython 2.7](https://doughellmann.com/blog/2012/11/12/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2/). En cualquier caso empiezo a preferir la sintaxis del contructor [es decir `dict()`] pues resulta más fácil de escribir y mover código entre diccionarios y llamadas a funciones.

El artículo que enlazan indicado dice (traduzco yo):

> Con CPython 2.7, usar `dict()` para crear diccionarios necesita hasta 6 veces más de tiempo e involucra más operaciones de asignación de memoria que la sintaxis literal. Usa `{}` para crear diccionarios, especialmente si los estás poblando de datos inicialmente, a menos que la sintaxis literal no funciona para tu situación.

Así que me pregunto: ¿Es esta diferencia de hasta seis veces en tiempo significativa? Pueden ser 6 veces, pero intuyo que seis veces algo infinitesimal. Además, ¿hay alguna diferencia de algún tipo en la definición? ¿Existe en Python 2.x o 3.x algún caso que esté pasando por alto o es un tema cuasi estilístico?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El artículo explica el motivo.

`dict` se compila a :

```
        0 LOAD_NAME                0 (dict)
          3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
          6 POP_TOP
          7 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Mientras que `{}` se compila a :

```
          0 BUILD_MAP                0
          3 POP_TOP
          4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
          7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Es decir, `dict` llama a una función (CALL_FUNCTION 0, que es el constructor), con lo que además de ejecutar esos 4 op codes también ha de ejecutar todo el código que hay en esa función.
Sin embargo `{}` usa directamente el op code `BUILD_MAP` que crea un diccionario vacío. Por eso es más rápido.

Pero nótese que :

- En los tests de esa página la diferencia es de 0.239 microsegundos a 0.0407 microsegundos.
- Esos resultados son válidos para esa versión. Una versión posterior optimizada podría generar el mismo código compilado para los dos casos.

Salvo que tengas un código que crea enormes cantidades de diccionarios no vas a notar la diferencia. Utiliza lo que te resulte más legible.

Comment: Por completar un poco la respuesta. En Python 3 los diccionarios se han optimizado bastante. En CPython 3.6.x usar `dict()` en lugar de `{}` puede ser hasta 4 veces más lento pero ambas opciones se crean en nanosegundos (en mi portátil de trabajo con un i5 normalillo).